# System Tray Icon

Tags: c#

Okay firstly I just started C# so I'm not exactly the most skilled programmer out there. Okay so here's my problem that may seem stupid to you guys ;)

I have a simple enough app that a friend asked me to do. So far I have managed with a bit of Google but I'm stuck with this. The app runs fine and minimizes to the system tray and maximizes from the system tray which is good. However, when I open a second form from that application it creates another icon in the system tray and starts duplicating every time I open another form. So eventually I have lots of icons and all of them are seperate instances of the main form. System Tray events

```
private void notifyIcon_systemTray_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
    {
        Show();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}
private void CronNecessityForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon_systemTray.Visible = true;
    if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
        Hide();

}
private void restoreContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Show();
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

To open the Form:

```
private void preferencesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CronPreferences.formPreferences CronPreferences = new CronPreferences.formPreferences();
    CronPreferences.Show();
}
```

Close it:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Hide();
}
```

How can I have all Forms map to the same icon in the System Tray?

Comment: And what is the question exactly?

Comment: I dont see the question. This behaviour is by your design what did you want to achieve instead?

Comment: sorry I see now how it seems a bit vague. How do I prevent it creating more icons like it is at the moment. it should create one when the program loads and thats it. I don't want it to create more each time I open another form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a single global tray icon that they all access. Do this by using a static variable that stays the same throughout different instances of the class.

Then, if you want to:

- Open one form: keep a reference to the latest form in a variable and open it.
- Open all minimised forms: iterate through each form and open them again.

Comment: I like this solution but the OP doesn't say whether all of the opened forms are of the same class / inherited class...

Comment: @ach Either way, the static variable will be the regardless of the class instance, no matter where it is implemented, at any view or controller level (though doing so at the view model might ruin any MVC framework you have)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to keep only a **single instance of your application** running. In that case, your title is a bit misleading since your problem has nothing to do with tray icons or multiple forms.

- [Code Project: A Single Instance Application which Minimizes to the System Tray when Closed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/singleinstanceapplication.aspx)

On the other hand, if you really have a **main form** in your app, which opens the **second form** (which creates a tray icon), in that case you simply need to make sure your second form is instantiated only once:

```
public class MainForm
{
    private SecondForm _secondForm;

    public void OpenSecondForm()
    {
         // create it only once
         if (_secondForm == null)
             _secondForm = new SecondForm();

         // otherwise just show it
         _secondForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think he wants a single instance, but multiple forms with one tray icon.

Comment: @ach. Yep thats true. I can use Groo's code and then set the notify icon to not be visable but thats taking a shortcut